# Exec a Environment Variables

Tags: bash

I set a environment vaiables and exec it

```
RUNSER="su -l shiyanlou -s /bin/bash -c 'codebox run /home/shiyanlou/Code' "
```

and

```
exec $RUNSER
```

why I get this error

```
run: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
run: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of fil
```

it read the last `'`???how can i fix it?

thank you

Comment: Try using `set -x`; it will show you what your `exec` command expands to (which is not what you think).

Comment: Quotes aren't processed after expanding variables. You need to use `eval`, not `exec`.

Comment: Thank you very much,It work.

Comment: This is http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Thank you @ruakh,,I know why will get this message. when I use `set -x`,I got this `RUNSER='su - shiyanlou -s /bin/bash -c '\''codebox run /home/shiyanlou/Code'\'''`